# Commands and dependencies for bluetooth Speaker to work for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: bluetooth, pulseaudio, alsa, bluez, bluetooth-speaker

I have a bluetooth speakers and bluetooth dongle. Bluetooth dongle connected to PC. Now i want to listen songs in my Bluetooth speakers.

So I need terminal commands to connect to my Bluetooth speaker and to play mp3 files. In hcitool scan I can see my bluetooth speakers.

What is the standard procedure to connect and play mp3 files in Bluetooth Speakers via command line?

What are the dependencies (includes Bluetooth, player, speaker, etc) required?

Comment: What did you try so far? What happened when you did?

Comment: first of all i want to know the dependencies to run. I searched in google their are different ways to connect. But I want to know the standard procedure to do. Because i posted here.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to clarify something or add information? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.